# Sitefinity Export Document & Files ,Images , Videos from one database to other without enterprize license

Tags: telerik, sitefinity

I need to export sitefinity content from Document & Files ,Images , Videos of one database to other. I know there is some synchronization feature which is only available to enterprise license which i don't have. Is there anyway that through some other way or database script i can export and import data.
I am using Database as storage for those content instead of file system.
I am using sitefinity version 6.3

Comment: In the end i have to help from my colleague to do content pop :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to do so, but you can always use the Sitefinity API to get the images, documents, videos, etc. and upload them to the new site.

The Sitefinity documentation is a good place to start:
http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/sitefinity-essentials/modules/media-modules/documents-and-files/managing-documents/modifying-documents